# How to Access Postgres Service from Child Docker Container in Gitlab-CI? How do I access IP address of postgres service or gitlab shared runner?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have setup a gitlab-ci build with the architecture illustrated below.

[image: architecture]
<sub>(source: [gitlab.com](https://forum.gitlab.com/uploads/default/original/2X/9/928b58e1d81ad5462d65142aee39694fde5641a9.png))</sub>
.

The listener container is unable to communicate with the postgres container using the hostname, ‘*postgres*’. The hostname is unrecognised. How can the listener container communicate with the postgres database instance?

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html) recommends configuring a postgres instance as a service in *.gitlab-cy.yml*. CI jobs defined in *.gitlab-ci.yml*, are able to connect to the postgres instance via the service name, '*postgres*'.

The *tusd*, *minio* and *listener* containers are spawned within a docker-compose process, triggered inside the *pytest* CI job. The *listener* container writes information back to the postgres database.

Subsequently, I thought about using the IP address of the postgres service in place of the hostname. From within the pytest CI build job I have tried to determine the IP address of the postgres database using the following bash command sequence:

- export DB_IP="$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' postgres)"
- echo "DB IP ADDRESS IS $DB_IP"

However, postgres is not recognised as a container.

How do I determine the IP address of the postgres service? Alternatively can I use the IP address of the shared runner? How do I determine this?

Does anybody have any ideas?

**Update 11/1/2019**
Resolved by moving all services into docker-compose file so that they can communicate with each other. This includes the postgres container etc…After some refactoring in test environment initialisation, tests are now invoked via docker-compose run command.

Now able to successfully run tests using gitlab-shared runner…